# Rewiring a house

Tags: electrical

I live in a small town, in an old house that needs to be rewired. It isn't easy finding certain repair people (i.e electricians) around here, but earlier this year I managed to get into contact with one. He came over and walked the house, said he would call me by the end of the week with an estimate. That never happened, plus he wouldn't answer his phone or emails when I tried contacting him. I run into electricians all the time in the town I work in but none of them service the county that I reside. Have been seriously considering taking an electrical course at a Vocational school or college and doing this myself. -any other options anyone can suggest?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: As both answers below suggest it is a good idea to check or just ask on this forum if a home owner can do there own work (provide the state and county). A class would be a good idea if it focuses on residential wiring. This could be taught and learned in a single semester. Basic wiring is simple and many people get books like wiring 1.2.3. I think there is a Dummies book but a quick search only showed electronics and that’s not what you want. A quick way to find out would be to go to your local home improvement store and ask about there books, and ask them they will probably know.

Comment: What vintage is this house, and can you provide photos of the existing main panel?  Also, how many square feet is it, how is it heated/cooled, and does it use gas or electric for the range, hot water heater, and dryer?  And yes, do check your AHJ's rules about owner-occupant work.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your local area and the rules there.

i.e. in my local area it's fine for homeowners and farmers (but not other commercial occupancies) to do their own electrical work. In other areas the rules are different. Check your area's rules.

Comment: I agree some states are crazy strict but most allow the home owner and direct family to do there own electrical.+

Answer (score 1):

Before you jump into something, check with your local jurisdiction -  there may be legal limitations on what electrical work can be done and immediately used without being signed off on by a licensed electrician or the code enforcement guy. Your utility company probably also requires a licensed electrician for any service upgrades.

And always get permits when required - it's insurance for your homeowners' insurance.

Comment: In most of the states I have worked in a home owner can do there own electrical even a service upgrade.